# Python - Adding variable to functions on the fly. Why is this possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a Java programmer making his way into Python, and some things are just baffling. For example, adding variables to functions, dynamically. For example:

```
def main():
    print ("Hello World")


main.temp = 50

print (main.temp)
```

**What does that even mean? Why would you want to add a variable to a function? Why is that allowed? And why am I allowed to reference the function via `main.temp`?**

Comment: Have you read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/?

Comment: Well, everything in python is an object, even functions.

Comment: Not unlike Javascript in this regard

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Why allow this? javascript has one of the worst syntaxes in this regards.

Comment: @ng.newbie why forbid it ? Being able to annotate a function with any arbitrary attribute is actually quite useful (and indeed used by some well-known frameworks).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Can you give a real-life example where this is actually used?

Comment: Most objects in Python permit you to add attributes, the exception being those defined in C, like most of the built-in types (int, str, list, etc).

Comment: FWIW, I quite like function attributes, but I admit they aren't popular, and there are generally better ways to do stuff that you can do using function attributes. But IMHO they are a convenient way to attach data to a function, and they're better than having a stray object floating around in the global space that's supposed to be associated with the function.

Comment: @PM2Ring Could you please elaborate by what you mean by "the exception being those defined in C"? You can define objects in C in Python? I am now completely lost.

Comment: I ought to mention that the lookup time on a function attribute is somewhat slow: first a lookup in the global namespace is performed to find the function itself, and then another lookup is performed to find the attribute. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34036910/4014959) to see some timeit tests I wrote that compare various caching strategies, the one using a function attribute is the slowest.

Comment: Django templates (to prevent some methods from being called from a template), Django admin (to give meaningfull label to computed listview fields), I know I've seen it in other frameworks but can't remember which ATM, and I've personnaly used this in at least a dozen projects for similar reasons: adding meta data to a function so some other piece of code can apply special treatments to those functions.

Comment: Standard Python is often known as CPython, because the interpreter is written in C, and the built-in types it defines are defined using C structures. It's also possible to write your own extensions to Python in C, although that's not often done by mere mortals. ;) But take a look [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c) for the C source of the standard  `list` object.

Answer (score 1):

Functions in Python are first-class objects which means you can do *almost* whatever you want to do with them. Heck, you can even do this:

```
def foo(): pass

foo.inner_foo = lambda: print('inner foo')

foo.inner_foo()
# inner foo
```

Yes, it is a function with an attribute which is a function. And yes, we *can* go deeper:

```
def foo(): pass

foo.inner_foo = lambda: None

foo.inner_foo.inner_inner_foo = lambda: print('inner inner foo')

foo.inner_foo.inner_inner_foo()
# inner inner foo
```

And yes, we *can* go deeper, but you get the idea...

Comment: When was this ever helpful? Why allow this feature? Just because functions are objects you shouldn't be allowed to add variables to it.

Comment: Django makes extensive use of this.  Just because you don't immediately see the utility does not make it worthless.

Comment: @ng.newbie "just because functions are objects you shouldn't be allowed to add variables to it."  **why?** that is almost literally the definition of first-class objects. And yes, this is very useful, see the answers to the linked duplicated question.

Comment: @DeepSpace Objects in Java don't allow the addition of variables after it is created. So that's why I said what I said. Is the definition of the object different in Python?

Comment: @James Could you please give an example of how Django uses this? Maybe if I saw a real life warranted use, then maybe this feature would annoy me a little less.